# Is it a good practice to use wordpress database to store pages contents which loading to page dynamically?

Tags: plugins, database

I have a wordpress instance with 150+ pages and a plugin. According to the page URL, plugin will bring contents(text and images) required for that page from a database. Can I use existing mySQL wordpress database to store this content also?

Comment: Isn't what Wordpress does this by default? Saving Page content to the Database? Not sure if is a question here.

Comment: Actually all my pages are blank pages. My plugin will dynamically fill the content in this pages from database. I want to know whether I can use wordpress db to store this content. At the moment plugin is retrieving content from an external database. This makes me manage two database.

Comment: Yes WP it will handle what you are asking and more. If you need help on the migration you can raise a new question to help you offering ideas and execution of the transition.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does this by default. It uses your existing MySQL database to store content from pages, posts and other types of content.

Take a look at the `wp_posts` and the `wp_postsmeta` tables in your database to find all your content stored there.

Also WordPress internally treats all pages as posts with a different `post_type` value (set to `page`).

See this for the present DB structure
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

See this if you want to create the tables dynamically with your plugin
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: Actually all my pages are blank pages. My plugin will dynamically fill the content in this pages from database. I want to know whether I can use wordpress db to store this content. At the moment plugin is retrieving content from an external database. This makes me manage two database.

Comment: Ofcourse, you can store the content as part of the WP database, either in separate tables or use the existing ones if they fit your needs. See my edited answer for more details